# Conversion of NA yearqtr to string in zoo: possible bug?

Tags: r, zoo

In `zoo` an `NA` yearqtr is converted to the string "NA QNA" (which is *not* NA).  For example

```
library(zoo)
qq <- as.yearqtr(c('2015 Q1', NA))
is.na(as.character(qq)) == is.na(qq) # returns TRUE FALSE
```

In contrast with base date we have:

```
dd <- as.Date(c('2015-1-1', NA))
is.na(as.character(dd)) == is.na(dd) # returns TRUE TRUE
```

My impression is that the date behavior is the expected behavior. Should I report this to `zoo`? (And if so, what is the best way to do so?  Email maintainer?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for pointing out this bug. And yes, the simplest way to report such problems is by e-mail to the maintainer (= me).

I've just fixed the problem in the development version of `zoo` (1.8-0 to be) on R-Forge. After running `install.packages("zoo", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")` you should get the expected behavior:

```
library("zoo")
qq <- as.yearqtr(c("2015 Q1", NA))
as.character(qq)
## [1] "2015 Q1" NA       
is.na(as.character(qq)) == is.na(qq)
## [1] TRUE TRUE
```

A new CRAN release is planned in the next days or next week.

Comment: Wow! Thank you. I will test it as soon as I can (certainly once it's on CRAN, perhaps while it's only in dev).

Comment: Just now released on the CRAN master site. Mirrors and binaries will follow in the next days...